# Parameter passing to method to remove object creation

Tags: c#, performance, memory

I have the following code in a project I just moved to and it raised a debate in our team whether this is the right approach or not:

```
public void Method()
{
    var reusableList = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
    {
        var result = HelperMethod(i, reusableList);
    }
}

private static object HelperMethod(int someObject, List<string> something)
{
    something.Clear();
    //do something with the list
    something.Add(someObject.ToString());
    return something[0];
}
```

The method "Method" run a loop processing some data using helper method for a lot of times (the code here is of course not the real code...) and the reusable list is passed to the helper method for memory reduction purposes and performance purposes. 
There is no use for that list in the method "Method" (which reduce readability of the code) but creating it over and over again will reduce performance and increase memory consumption, what is the best approach here?

Comment: Please put some care into formatting your code when asking a question - just a few more seconds of effort can make a big difference in readability.

Comment: "creating it over and over again will reduce performance and increase memory consumption" - have you verified that that's the case? Note that you'll end up with fewer objects, but they'll be longer-lasting. The garbage collector is very good at dealing with short-lived objects.

Comment: Have you tested the code? What performance hit are you worried about. My advice is not to attempt to optimize a code segment unless you are sure that it is causing an issue. This operation of creating and deleting a `List<string>` is unlikely to be a bottle neck for your code...

Comment: Cost of lost readability here is much more than achieved performance improvement - which is probably very small, as creating `List` is not so heavy operation in fact.

Comment: I think I must add something - when I first saw this pattern in the code I was horrified since it goes against everything I know, but while doing memory testing we saw that it reduced memory since it is 1 long lasting list vs creating a few million lists which are garbage collected later on.
This code is part of a larger code which need to be very fast and with a small memory footprint.
It is really hard to measure the overall effect of this optimization on the system and an isolated test doesn't show very well what will happen on the full application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List<T>` uses an array internally. If you add new items to the list and there is no room left in the array, a new array of the double size will be allocated and all object in the current array will be copied over to the new array. This requires some time.Depending on the amount of items in your array, this could have an impact. Especially when adding a lot of items to it. When using a "shared" instance of a list like you did, the internal array of `List<T>` will not shrink when you call `List<T>.Clear()`. After a while of using this instance, you don't have this overhead any more. As an alternative, when expecting a lot of items in your list, you could specify the initial capacity of the list in the constructor.

That means: it's faster in theory. But i doubt that you really recognize a difference.

I'd prefer good code readability

Comment: not sure what you mean by: "cood reaFirst"
I know clear doesn't change the size of the internal array and if the size of the list needed is roughly the same this only make this much more helpful from performance stand point, isn't it?

Comment: sorry. fixed this sentence. Again, it depends on the situation. If you really need performance, object caching/reuse might be a feasible way.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `Method()` is not executed over and over again by the `for` loop. If you are talking about `HelperMethod()` then, calling it over and over again will not have any memory problems because once it is executed all the resources created by it (`int and List<string>`) will be disposed.